# How to configure ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory to use a ElasticsearchRepository in a standalone program with ElasticsearchCustomConversions

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot application with a working configuration where `ElasticsearchCustomConversions` are used. Works fine.

Inside this application I want to create some standalone src/test/java classes where I can test my `ElasticsearchRepository` logic. Standalone because starting Spring Boot every time is too time consuming.

I am able to use a `ElasticsearchRepository` in a standalone java program like:

```
public class ExampleRepositoryStandaloneTester {

private static ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory factoryBean;

static {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("localhost:9200").build();
    RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations = new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client);
    factoryBean = new ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory(elasticsearchOperations);
}

public static ProductRepository getProductRepository() {
    return factoryBean.getRepository(ProductRepository.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Product count: " + getProductRepository().count());
}}
```

The count function is really going to my local docker Elastic instance and prints the Product count. So this works.

But, my model needs `ElasticsearchCustomConversions` and I cannot find a way to properly setup the  `ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory` so that the conversion are configured and used.

Does anyone know how to do this?

- Spring Boot v2.3.4.RELEASE
- ​Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.4.RELEASE
- Elasticsearch 7.6.2

Versions are dependency managed through a RedHat fuse version so I cannot (easily) upgrade to newer versions.

The following attempt fails with "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Boolean] to type [com.my.TrueFalseType]":

```
public class ExampleCustomConversionsTester {

static class ExampleConfigurator extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
    private RestHighLevelClient client;
    
    public ExampleConfigurator(RestHighLevelClient client) {
        ExampleConfigurator.this.client = client;
    }
    
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        return client;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
        return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Collections.singletonList(new TrueFalseTypeConverter()));
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    static class TrueFalseTypeConverter implements Converter<Boolean, TrueFalseType> {
        @Override
        public TrueFalseType convert(Boolean value) {
            return TrueFalseType.fromValue(value.toString());
        }
    }
}

static {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("localhost:9200").build();
    RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    ExampleConfigurator cfg = new ExampleConfigurator(client);

    ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations = new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(cfg.elasticsearchClient());
    MappingElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter = (MappingElasticsearchConverter) elasticsearchOperations.getElasticsearchConverter();
    elasticsearchConverter.setConversions(cfg.elasticsearchCustomConversions());
    factoryBean = new ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory(cfg.elasticsearchOperations(elasticsearchConverter));
}

private static ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory factoryBean;

public static ProductRepository getProductRepository() {
    return factoryBean.getRepository(ProductRepository.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Product count: " + getProductRepository().count());
    Page<Product> page = getProductRepository().findProducts(PageRequest.of(0, 10));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the conversions with

```
    elasticsearchConverter.setConversions(cfg.elasticsearchCustomConversions());
```

you need to call

```
elasticsearchConverter.afterPropertiesSet()
```

as described in the Javadoc for the `setConversions` method. Normally Spring does this, but as you are not using Spring to setup the beans, you need to do this in your code.